# passenger stop kill orphan process

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, linux

My app is rails and python .

In rails I create a new thread and start a shell command which executes python scripts.
This python script (parent process) will exit quickly, but before it exits it will fork a child process, and the child process will be an orphan process after the parent process exits.

Situation 1:
If I start app by rails: `rails s -d`

When the python parent process exits and python child process is going:
`kill  pid(./tmp/pids/server.pid)`

Then the child process will be ok and not be killed. This is what I want.

Situation 2:
If I start app by passenger:
`passenger start -e production -d`

When the python parent process exits and python child process is going:
`passenger stop;`
then the child process will be killed.

So I  want to know in situation 2, the child orphan process could not be killed? Has anyone experienced this or knows how to solve it?

Comment: I find it is because passenger make my python script and PassengerHelperAgent the same group process id.so when passenger stop it will kill all  process which are the same with PassengerHelperAgent 
group process id . [reference link](http://old.blog.phusion.nl/2012/09/21/the-right-way-to-deal-with-frozen-processes-on-unix/)
but i do not know how to prevent passenger not to kill my script.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve my problem by
restart my app instead of restart passenger
restart app command: passenger-config restart-app [path of my app]